# Python parsing json data

Tags: python, json

I have a json object saved inside `test_data` and I need to know if the string inside `test_data['sign_in_info']['package_type']` contains the string "vacation_package" in it. I assumed that `in` could help but I'm not sure how to use it properly or if it´s correct to use it. This is an example of the json object:

```
"checkout_details": {
        "file_name" : "pnc04",
        "test_directory" : "test_pnc04_package_today3_signedout_noinsurance_cc",
        "scope": "wdw",
          "number_of_adults": "2",
          "number_of_children": "0",
          "sign_in_info": {
              "should_login": false,
              **"package_type": "vacation_package"**
          },
```

`package type` has "vacation_package" in it, but it's not always this way.
For now I´m only saving the data this way:

```
package_type = test_data['sign_in_info']['package_type']
```

Now, is it ok to do something like:

```
p= "vacation_package"
if(p in package_type):
    ....
```

Or do I have to use 're' to cut the string and find it that way?

Comment: is `test_data['sign_in_info']['package_type'] == 'vacation_package'` not appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer depends on what exactly you expect to get from `test_data['sign_in_info']['package_type']`. Will `'vacation_package'` always be by itself? Then `in` is fine. Could it be part of a larger string? Then you need to use `re.search`. It might be safer just to use `re.search` (and a good opportunity to practice regular expressions).

Comment: That's my concern. "vacation_package" may noy always be alone, sometimes comes with something like "vacation_package_tickets". So re would be a good solution?

Comment: Using `re.search` would definitely work. You might be able to use just `==`, but that would fail in the case of something like `"vacation_package, vacation_package_tickets"`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `re`, assuming you are using the `json` package. Yes, it's okay to do that, but are you trying to see if there is a "package type" listed, or if the package type contains `vacation_package`, possibly among other things? If not, this might be closer to what you want, as it checks for exact matches:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('file.json'))

if data['sign_in_info'].get('package_type') == "vacation_package":
   pass # do something
```